# Weekly and Biweekly Std Deviation for total rowcount by grouping parameteres

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to calculate standard deviation according to 3 grouping columns System, Type, T_Type.

The query should calculate weekly and biweekly deviation for row count according to above grouped parameters.

In the grouping parameters each system has all T_Type but it can have different Type values.
Find below the sample data. Tables contains dated rowcount for grouped values each day.

[image]

Comment: I cannot see any System, Type, T_Type columns in your dataset, please have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @McNets Sorry uploaded the new picture

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=214233bdae6a8896b6af25f0758440dc) fiddle. Feel free to edit it, use your own table and insert data, then copy the link to your question or copy and paste DDL statments, or simply take it as a guidance to solve your question.

Comment: I think you only considered one group parameter. I have to group by 3 parameters. Slightly correct but when I modify code to group by conditions I want it gives me wrong answer.

Comment: I know you have 3 params and it must be calculated by week, it is just an example. Change it by using your own table/data and post the link, I cannot copy all this data from your picture.